# How to add external armatures to existing object

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm trying to make an animation using an object that I found on the web ([object.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5PR8wODbC6tTERjYUlBX1VxZ1U)) and binding an animation ([stick.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5PR8wODbC6tdTVFT3BJcnhVTEk)) on it that I've prepared with help of a document that I found on the web.

I merge these two files, align and scale bones and finally set parent using "with automatic weights". The result is awful. I also tried "with empty groups" and "with envelope weights" but no chance.

When I repeat similar operations with a simple stick, it works as expected. What should be the correct way of merging these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you parent with automatic weights, go into the armature edit mode and align all the bones with the mesh. So that each bone is where it is supposed to be.

Then go into pose mode and clear the location/rotation of all the bones.

Then apply the automatic weights.

[here](https://gfycat.com/NervousEquatorialAlaskankleekai) is a .gif of how to do it